# Switch to say "yes" to all questions in a cmd / batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, switch-statement

I am in need of a command or switch that will answer all queries in a cmd file e.g.:

cacls C:\Users\test.txt /D SYSTEM

Prompts if you are sure you want do perform the action, how would I overcome it?

Any help on this matter would come as a great help

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
echo Y | cacls ...
```

Reference: [CACLS](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html).

Comment: Note: This depends on the OS language, though. It might be `J` or another character.